# Powershell: How to copy source document and rename it from a list in a text file?

Tags: powershell

I have this document that needs to be copied every month to every college with their name as its new name

so i would like to take my source document and copy it and renamed it from a list i have in a text file.

This is what i tried:

```
$source = "C:\Users\BackZ\Documents\environment\Source\Booking og lønafregning Blank.xls"
$Namelist = get-content "C:\Users\BackZ\Documents\environment\Source\List.txt"
Get-ChildItem $source | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -Replace 'Booking og lønafregning Blank.xls',set-content $Namelist}
```

Im pretty new at this so please bare that in mind when you answer.

i have already looked at several other post her and on other site but non seems to have the same needs as this in a why that i can understand what they're doing

so i'm looking for some guidens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code, I am making the following assumptions:

1. You want the copied/renamed documents to be in the same folder as the source document and the list of names
2. The list of names contains one college name per line.

On that basis, the following should work:

```
Push-Location "C:\Users\BackZ\Documents\Environment\Source"
$NameList = Get-Content "List.txt"
ForEach ($Name in $NameList) {
    Copy-Item -Path "Booking og lønafregning Blank.xls" -Destination ("$Name"+".xls") -Force
}
Pop-Location
```